# maximum operator on array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is a syntaxic question. a sum can be extracted via

```
@cart.quotes.sum("weight")
```

But this does not apply to max

```
@cart.quotes.max("weight")
```

In another syntaxic mode

```
@cart.quotes.weight.max
```

generates "undefined method "weight" for Relation. I fail to understand both the applicability (or non) of the operator, as how the Relation error can appear for a variable I can operate upon...  Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer first question, try:

```
@cart.quotes.maximum("weight")
```

About the applicability (or non) of the operator: `@cart.quotes` returns an ActiveRecord Relation that does not have any method or attribute called `weight` or any other attribute that the table `quotes` has.

However it does respond to operators like `sum` and `maximum` that do that operation on the provided attribute and return the final calculation.

See the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) for ActiveRecord Calculation methods.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Did not realize that the .min or .max shorthand was not universally available